# Select which array to write to based on variables given to a function, Lua

Tags: arrays, lua

I am trying to run this code:

```
function calcs.grps(Number,ion_color)
    grp .. ion_color .. Y[Number] = (ion_py_mm)
    grp .. ion_color .. Z[Number] = (ion_pz_mm)
end
```

in a Lua script, the arrays already exist (eg grp2Y,grp5Z etc) and I want to use this function to populate them based upon the two variables fed in. I keep getting the error ' '=' expected near '..' '. What am I doing wrong?

To flesh it out a bit:

I am 'flying' 120 ions in my simulation. This is actually 12 groups of 10 ions. The individual groups of 10 are distinguished by ion_color, which is an integer value from 1 to 12. The variable 'Number' just cycles through 1 to 10 each time before moving on to the next color. Once I have populated these arrays I want to get the standard deviation for each group.

Thank you!

Comment: Lua is a proper name, not an acronym. Don't use ALL CAPS for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "construct" name of variable, but you can construct an index. Use two levels of nested tables.

```
function calcs.grps(Number,ion_color)
    ion['grp' .. ion_color .. 'Y'][Number] = (ion_py_mm)
    ion['grp' .. ion_color .. 'Z'][Number] = (ion_pz_mm)
end
```

Well, actually you can, since all global variables are just entries in `_G` table, but don't do that since it is bad - it is unreadable, makes stuff spill to other functions you didn't intend to, etc.

Comment: ah that makes so much sense now. I'm quite new to it all so I'm picking it all up as I go.  this also means I only need to make one empty array called 'ion', thank you!

Comment: You'll also need to manually construct empty sub-tables on first level - there's no autovivification as in som other languages. You can use something like `ion['grp' .. ion_color .. 'Y'] = ion['grp' .. ion_color .. 'Y'] or {}; ion['grp' .. ion_color .. 'Y'][Number] = (ion_py_mm)`

Answer (score 1):

The technical answer to your question is to simply index _G, _G is a table which holds all global variables:

```
function calcs.grps(Number,ion_color)
    _G['grp' .. ion_color .. Y'][Number] = (ion_py_mm)
    _G['grp' .. ion_color .. 'Z'][Number] = (ion_pz_mm)
end
```

But I think the better question, is why aren't you organizing it like this...

```
local ions = {
    Red = {
        {
            Y = 0, --Y property
            Z = 0 --Z property
        },
        --Continue your red ions
    },
    NewColor = {
            Y = 0, --Y property
            Z = 0 --Z property
        },
        --Continue this color's ions
    },
    --You get the idea
}

function calcs.grps(color, number)
    ions[color][number].Y = (ion_py_mm)
    ions[color][number].Z = (ion_pz_mm)
end
```

Then you would pass a color, and a number indicating which ion of this color

It looks a lot cleaner, IMO.

Comment: I hadn't seen that notation before, it looks a lot cleaner!

I don't quite understand your question. The variable 'number' is generated by the software I'm using and goes from 1 to the total number of ions flown (120 in this case). It doesn't pay attention to how the ions of different properties are grouped. I'm using the ion color to group them instead.

Comment: @Nick You mean the period? It's syntactic sugar from keys that are strings. Just like instead of ```{['hi']=1,['hello']=2}``` you can just use ```{hi=1,hello=2}``` (I hope you make great use of this)

Comment: @Nick Give me like 2 min to rewrite my answer a bit

Comment: @Nick Let's nuke our comments, and look at the new code

Comment: Now we're on the same page! I'd never seen it typed out like that before either so that's a second thing you've taught me so far. I will move over to doing it this way, much neater. one more small question if you don't mind, how would I then use the 'pairs' function on nested tables?

Comment: Exactly what would you want to iterate? The ions of a specific color? `for i,v in pairs(ions.Red) do`

Comment: to iterate over just the Y values or just the Z values (get a standard deviation over each axis). would what you wrote iterate over all Y and Z values in one go?

Comment: `for i,v in ipairs(ions.Red) do print(v.Y, v.Z) end`

Comment: so why is ipairs better here and what does the 'v' in 'v.Y' stand for?

Comment: @Nick ipairs iterates over an array, since the color tables contain Numeric keys, we can use ipairs for efficiency. ipairs functions almost identical to pairs in what it returns, a key, and it's corresponding value. (i, v). So the v is the ion. The Y/Z are the members of the ion.

Comment: My apologies if that was confusing